# How do you check the version number of a sql server clr?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlclr

What is the best way to check / version a sql server clr?
I am currently creating a SqlFunction that returns a version number (which I set before release).  This allows me to query the version e.g.

```
select mySchema.GetClrAppVersion
```

Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASSEMBLYPROPERTY()

SEE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188750.aspx